# Is it possible to recover a file while the deleted code is still running?

Tags: python, visual-studio

Ok so I accidentally deleted a folder that I was working on. Somehow the python script is still running (I was testing some stuff) in the terminal and it's running fine. It's under a cycle that never ends so it will keep running until I kill it. So I've figured that the file has to exist somewhere I'm using the visual studio code to run and edit the code, and i'm new to programming, just learning the basics of python. But the file was kinda important, so it would be cool to recover it.

Comment: Why don't you save it from vs code? Press ctrl+s and check the folder that you are working on it.

Comment: The editor closed when I deleted it

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531085/getting-the-source-code-of-a-running-python-script-externally

Comment: The file certainly doesn’t exist: Python closes them after executing their contents to create in-memory objects.

Comment: Per Thomas, does this answer your question? [Getting the source code of a running Python script externally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531085/getting-the-source-code-of-a-running-python-script-externally)

Comment: It does, thank you!